# rename packages to maven folder structure

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, web-applications, package, directory

I am converting my J2EE web application project in to maven folder structure as I have to generate sonar report using maven builder.
My first quotation is do I need to convert all modules which are present in my work space?
and second one, is there any way do rename the packages in eclipse after changing folder structure? As I have many packages and java files, it’s difficult to change manually

Answer (score 0):

If you're generally happy with the folder structure that you have, Maven does not force you to change it, just tell it where your source folders are:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

Now, having said that... as a Maven aficionado the Maven source folders feel like a warm bath. And I would try to change from such as `ejbModule` to `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` accordingly.

But you can just move the folders around. As long as they are in the configured (above) folders, Eclipse ([m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)) will pick up on it.

So, to make this work, you would be changing "source folders" (Eclipse terminology). The "source folders" contain packages (on the file system also represented by folders) which do not need to change to work with Maven. If you would decide to change packages as well, I'd always do that from within Eclipse, as to leverage the refactoring support and have your package name changes applied throughout.